# Is the mission "On the Blood Path" a reference to anything?

Tags: borderlands-3

Is this mission a reference to anything at all? I can't place my finger on it but searching up "We're on the blood path now" doesn't give me anything, and discussions about the quote say it's either referencing Game of Thrones or the Van Helsing show.

For reference, the NPC keeps singing "♫ we're on the blood path now ♫" over and over, each one getting more eerie than the last

Comment: Some say it's a reference to Game of Thrones and/or Van Helsing... Sadly, I haven't watched either yet, so I don't know if it's true. ([reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/borderlands3/comments/d6067v/were_on_the_blood_path_now/))

Comment: Ramdsen sounds like Ramsay Bolton, while Holden sounds like Hodor, both from GoT. It could be that, but I don't recognize the song quote